# MemoryError using numpy argsort

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, anaconda

I'm trying to sort a large numpy array. It is a 4 dimensional 'float16' array with shape (450, 470, 10, 470) (994,050,000 elements). When loaded the array size is about 2 GB and I'm using 64 bit linux (and 64-bit python) so I should be able to use all my 8GB of RAM without issues, but as soon as I try to use argsort, I get a MemoryError.

The code is the following:

```
import numpy as np

score = np.load('score.npy')
aaarg = np.argsort(score, axis=None)[:-21:-1]
```

My aim is to obtain the indexes of biggest 20 elements of the array. I also tried using argpartition instead of argsort but I encountered the same issue. Is there any way out?

I'm using python 2.7.9 (Anaconda 2.2.0) with numpy 1.9.2
Thanks.

Comment: You could break it into parts using `np.savetxt`, sort the parts, and then get the highest n values

Comment: Did you try ``score.sort()``? Since it does in-place sorting, its probably much more memory efficient. I would guess that ``argsort()`` needs at least three times the memory of ``score`` (the original, a copy to sort and  the returned indexes).

Comment: Sorting one part of the array at time and then sorting the results worked, thanks for the idea. Since i need the indexes i can't use just sort().

Answer (score 2):

First it should be pointed out that `argsort` returns an array of indices that index data into a sorted array. For example:

```
a = np.random.random(100)
idx = a.argsort()
b = a[idx]
```

The dtype of `idx` will be int64 if you're using 64bit python & numpy so lets do some math. 994,050,000 * 8bytes / 1024**3 bytes / GB = 7.4 GB. That doesn't include the `score` array or any system/python overhead.

While you should be able to do an in-place sort, you're not going to be able to do an argsort in memory on an array that size.

Comment: Ah ok, I was hoping that by taking only the last 20 elements of the index array (with [:-21:-1] ), I would avoid this issue.

Comment: @MicheleValentini there are a lot of tricks you could use in this specific case. There are only "2**16" unique float16 values so you should never need to "sort" 1e9 of them. You could use some fancy tricks with `numpy.bincount` instead. If you only need the 20 largest of the values you could also use `argmax` which should both be reasonably fast and not need extra memory.